# Can't open a downloaded PDF in Adobe or Viewer via Intent

Tags: android, pdf

I'm trying to open a .pdf via a new Intent. The intent fires and the pdf app selection fires. When I select either app. The app displays 'unable to open document' I am passing data/data/com.android.providers.downloads/cache/document.pdf as the Uri which I am suspecting is the problem. There is no sd card. The pdf will open fine via the dowloads folder. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is this file created by you? if so you can always make it world readable before you pass it to other apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am passing data/data/com.android.providers.downloads/cache/document.pdf as the Uri

That file is not readable by third party applications.

> The pdf will open fine via the dowloads folder.

Your main choices are to store the PDF on external storage (such as "the dowloads folder"), or to create a `ContentProvider` that can serve the file out of internal storage. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Files) demonstrates such a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Is it not readable by other applications because it resides in data/data/app_name?

Comment: @EGHDK: Yes. Internal storage is read-write for the app, deny-all for all other processes.

Comment: I have created a new Dir to store the downloads in via setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.Downloads). When I call getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(...) the dir is there with the file. When I try and open the file via the new Intent, Adobe is unable to open.

Comment: @SoundsDangerous: "is unable to open" is a useless description of your symptoms.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I took a crash course in Content Providers last night and implemented the FileProvider obj from the sample project you linked. I think a provider is the perfect solution for this situation. Thank you.